# How to trim or remove black part from image in php imagick?

Tags: php, imagick

I have created an image using Imagick in PHP[image]. But there is a black part in the background. I want to remove it. For more clarification, i have attached the image.

`

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('image.png');
$image->trimImage(.2);
echo $image;`
```

Comment: "For more clarification", please, add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine for me. Your Imgagick Version has to be 6.2.9 or higher: https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.trimimage.php

Have you tried using `$image->trimImage(0.2)` ?